# How to Set up a 2D Char Array with random Characters?

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am tackling a problem where I am trying to get a percentage of characters and populate them randomly in a 5x5 array using Math.random to store 25 items in a 2d array. I have come up with this right now but I don't see why it isn't populating the chars I want. It only is doing the 'X' and not randomly either, it appears to be in order with the total number of X. I am trying to output a percentage of X's, O's and what ever is left over to be blank. It is only outputting the 10 X's and they don't appear to be randomized. I would appreciate any advice I can get to why this is happening.

```
public static void main(String []args){

        char [][] tissue = new char [5][5];

        assignCellTypes(tissue,40,40);

    }

    public static void assignCellTypes(char[][] tissue,int percentO, int percentX){


                double cellx=0.0;
                double cellO=0.0;
                double totalO=0;
                double totalX = 0;
                totalO = (double)percentO/100;


                totalX = (double)
                        percentX/100;

                        cellx = totalX *(tissue.length*tissue.length);
                        cellO = totalO *(tissue.length*tissue.length);

            int i;
            int j ;
        for(int row = 0;row<tissue.length;row++){
            for(int col = 0;col<tissue[row].length;col++){


                    if(cellx>0){
                        i = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*tissue.length);
                        j = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*tissue.length);

                        tissue[i][j] = 'X';
                        System.out.print(tissue[i][j] + "  ");

                        cellx--;

                        if(cellO>0 && tissue[i][j] != 'X' ){
                            i = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*tissue.length);
                            j = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*tissue.length);

                            tissue[i][j] = 'O';
                            System.out.print(tissue[i][j] + "  ");
                            cellO--;

                    if(tissue[i][j] != 'X' && tissue[i][j] != 'O'){

                        tissue[i][j] = ' ';

                        System.out.print(tissue[i][j] + "  ");

                    }
                        }



                    }


            }
            System.out.println();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what you're trying to archieve, but it seems you're just trying to fill a char array randomly with `X` and `O` and a chance factor, in this case there's a much more simple solution

```
public static void assignCellTypes(char[][] tissue, int percentO, int percentX)
{
    double chanceO = percentO / (double) ( percentO + percentX );

    Random r = new Random(); //java.util.Random

    for(int i=0; i < tissue.length; i++)
        for(int j=0; j < tissue[i].length; j++)
            if( r.nextDouble() <= chanceO )
                tissue[i][j] = 'O';
            else
                tissue[i][j] = 'X';
}
```

EDIT @comment, I think this is what you want to achieve:

```
public static void assignCellTypes(char[][] tissue, int percentO, int percentX)
{
    if(percentO + percentX > 100)
        throw new Exception("You can't have more than 100%!");

    double chanceO = percentO/100d;
    double chanceX = percentX/100d;

    Random r = new Random(); //java.util.Random

    for(int i=0; i < tissue.length; i++)
        for(int j=0; j < tissue[i].length; j++)
        {
            double random = r.nextDouble();

            if( random <= chanceO )
                tissue[i][j] = 'O';
            else if( random <= chanceO + chanceX )
                tissue[i][j] = 'X';
        }
}
```

Comment: What i'm trying to achieve is fill the char array randomly with a specific percentage of X and O. So if my array can fill 25 items (5x5 array) and my X percentage and O is 40 each, thats 10 O's and 10 X's and the rest five I want to be blank spaces. All randomly through Math.random(). I get the random util way, I am trying to do this through Math.random(). I don't see why only X's are printing in my code, but not randomly and not the O's.

Comment: @NickCage The reason it's only printing X is because the code checks if cellx > 0, then writes an X randomly, does cellx--, then checks if there's not an X in the spot you just wrote an X to, and starts over again until cellx is smaller than 1. after that it just loops without doing anything. You should format your code a little better, it's quite unreadable in its current state. I made some edits to my answer, please check if my code works for you

Comment: No it is not in grid form and it is printing out 30 characters in a 5x5 2d array

Comment: That's because it only prints when it puts a char, and if it has put a char it prints another time, and since it's only putting Xes everywhere it only prints X